# Colorscales using Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I'm having some troubles trying to chance the colorgradient of a heat map using Plots. The documentation lacks of an example in the section Color (https://juliaplots.github.io/colors/). I think that the default color gradient is `:inferno` but I don't like it. Does someone know a complete list of standard gradients or a way to make my own color gradient?

```
x_range = linspace(0, 2, 100)
y_range = linspace(0,2, 100)
z = rand(100, 100)
heatmap(x_range, y_range, z, color = :blues)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel like there's a lot of detail in that doc page, and the linked notebook.  However this should be helpful:

```
julia> z = (1:100)*(1:200)';

julia> p = plot(layout=length(PlotUtils._gradients), axis=nothing, leg=false, size=(800,800))

julia> for (i,cmap) in enumerate(keys(PlotUtils._gradients))
           heatmap!(p[i], z, fillcolor=cmap, title=string(cmap))
       end; p
```

[image]